# Run JavaScript function after Ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two functions that I want to run after the Ajax call succeeds but only one work.

The Javascript code is working if I put it outside the Ajax call and it worked as an onclik. Basically, I click an element and fill the value of the input of this element in another. But now I want to fill the value only after the call succeeds.

The original code:

```
$('*[id^="newbudbtn-"]').on('click', showMessage); //This is the line I want to be executed after the Ajax call

function showMessage(event) {
    var elem = $(event.target);
    var id = elem.attr('id').replace('newbudbtn-', '');

    var source = $('#newbud-' + id)
    var target = $('#bud-' + id);

    if (source.length && target.length) {
      target.text('$' + source.val());
    }
}
```

This is the Ajax call. "myAlertTop();" is working, but I can't get "showMessage()" to do the same.

```
$("a.bgbtb").click(function(){
  var btnid = $(this).attr("id").split('newbudbtn-')[1];
  var newbudget = $("INPUT[id=newbud-"+btnid+"]").val();
  var platform = $("span#"+btnid).text(); 
  $.ajax({
    url:"campbdgtedit.php",
    method:"POST",  
    data:{platform:platform, btnid:btnid, newbudget:newbudget}, 
    success:function(data){
        myAlertTop();
        $('*[id^="newbudbtn-"]').on('click', showMessage);

    }
  });
});
```

I understand that the onlick won't work, so I tried desperately onload and also calling the function directly, but nothing seems to work. I also tried echoing the JS inside campbdgtedit.php, but it didn't work too.

The major issue is that there are many clickable elements, one on each row of a table, and only the element on the same row should be changed.

Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Could you add a short sample of the HTML?

Comment: could you post your code online?

Comment: I have jsfiddle of the input and element that should be filled here https://jsfiddle.net/scdf0y5u/

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you are trying to achieve but I think at first you should remove the ```onClick="showMessage()"``` attributes from the HTML, you want to add them later in the JS after clicking. It makes no sense to add them twice.

Comment: I didn't add the onclick twice, it was only to illustrate my attempt to solve the problem, but as I said in the question, it makes no sense to have the onclick inside the Ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you can update your `showMessage()` to accept the element itself instead of an event.

updated `showMessage`

```
function showMessage(elem) {   
    var id = elem.getAttribute('id').replace('newbudbtn-', '');

    var source = '#newbud-' + id;
    var target = '#bud-' + id;

    console.log(source);
    console.log(target);
}
```

And now you can call this method directly after ajax success, so your ajax success method will look something like

```
$("a.bgbtb").click(function(){
  const _btn = this;
  var btnid = $(this).attr("id").split('newbudbtn-')[1];
  var newbudget = $("INPUT[id=newbud-"+btnid+"]").val();
  var platform = $("span#"+btnid).text(); 
  $.ajax({
    url:"campbdgtedit.php",
    method:"POST",  
    data:{platform:platform, btnid:btnid, newbudget:newbudget}, 
    success:function(data){
        myAlertTop();
        showMessage(_btn);
    }
  });
});
```

jsfiddle link for reference https://jsfiddle.net/4ahef7mt/2/ hope this helps.

Comment: I'm hardly trying to make your code to work with no success. I don't understand the _btn and I keep getting this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: _btn is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

You should try using fetch and then. As soon as the request is received and the response is given, it executes the 'then(callback)'. That way you could call your function and pass the received data.

```
fetch(url, {request config}).then((response) => {

 /*write code and use the data */ 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Victoria Lucet. The problem is this s the first time I use Ajax  and I have no clue what I should fetch for in the URL as there is nothing that is returned from the page that the Ajax call is sent to.